# Sesame scalability

Tags: scalability, rdf, sesame

How to scale up Sesame? I'm planning to store a lot of triples in my Sesame and I'm wondering what I should do in order to have a scalable solution.

Ideally I would like my (native) store distribuited among several sesame instances, so a first question is: is there a way to "shard" sesame? If so, could you please point me to some kind of documentation?

In case of using a relational store, should I rely on a relational backend store?

In general, other than hardware resources and front-end load-balancers, what kind of support Sesame provides for medium / big data scenarios?

Comment: What amounts of triples do you have in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to scale up. I won't give you a complete overview of all possibilities here but give you a few pointers instead.

A single Sesame native store scales to about 100-150 million triples on typical hardware. Beyond that, you can either use a third-party Sesame-compatible store such as USeekM, Bigdata, CumulusRDF or OWLIM (which scales well into the billions of triples), or you can use Sesame's own [Federation SAIL](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/apidocs/index.html?org/openrdf/sail/federation/Federation.html). The federation members can be any combination of Sesame-compatible stores, including native stores running locally or remote stores accessible over HTTP.

The Federation SAIL distributes write operations using a simple size-dependent sharding algorithm, trying to distribute data over all members equally. Queries are of course automatically distributed and results re-integrated.

Comment: There is also Stardog which implements the Repository API but uses a custom backend.

Answer (score 1):

Sesame's relational backend is [deprecated now](http://www.openrdf.org/issues/browse/SES-1071). [Explanation on their mailing list](http://sesame-general.435816.n3.nabble.com/Deprecating-the-RDBMS-Sail-td4025195.html).

I am not sure but I think that Sesame wouldn't scale well with its native backends. As far as I know, people tend to use for example OWLIM. You would perhaps need [OWLIM-Enterprise](http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/editions) (previously BigOWLIM Replication Cluster) if you want a cluster solution.

If Sesame is not a hard requirement, then many people use the clustered edition of Virtuoso to store large amounts of triples.